# Bash or any other script not executing in android

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I have rooted my phone and want to execute a bash script which is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
svc wifi disable
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs
LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs/libfake_driver.so sh
cd /data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/tools
./enable_bcmon
echo "rfasuccess"
exit
```

If I execute the script like `sh file.sh` it's working but I really want to execute it as `./file.sh` when ever i execute it in `./file.sh` it gives an error called no such files or folders are found.

PS: I have used busybox also but still not working 
and am executing this using terminal emulator.

Any solution would be great.

Comment: try changing the permissions of this file to be executable, `chmod 755 ./file.sh`

Comment: i did try but still no success :(